# Why does my status bar disappear after a couple of seconds Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-statusbar

When I run my app on simulator or device, my status bar (time, battery, service) is visible for about 2 seconds during the launch screen and then disappears and doesn't come back.

I have tried many variations within the info.plist file, changing `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` and `NO`. trying different `Status bar style` and `Status bar is initially hidden` combinations. I don't know where i am going wrong.

EDIT:
I have rebuilt the whole app as a trouble shoot but it does the exact same thing still. Does anyone know what else I can try? I have spent two days searching for answers.

Can someone please help me?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I changed the `IOS_IS_WINDOWED` variable in my `main.m` file from `False` to `True` :)

```
putenv("IOS_IS_WINDOWED=True");
```